# I'm trying to display the top 50 frequent terms in a wordcloud format. I believe I'm missing something on server code

Tags: r

I'm trying to display the 50 most frequent words from pages retrieved from Wikipedia. I think I set up wordcloud portion right. I'm having trouble finding the right way to render it on the server side. Do I just simply use the renderWordcloud function or just plot?

This is my UI code

```
library(shiny)
titles <- c("Web_analytics","Text_mining","Integral", "Calculus", 
            "Lists_of_integrals", "Derivative","Alternating_series",
            "Pablo_Picasso","Vincent_van_Gogh","Leo_Tolstoy","Web_crawler")
# Define UI for application 
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  # Application title (Panel 1)
  titlePanel("Wiki Pages"), 
  # Widget (Panel 2) 
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(h3("Search panel"),
                 # Where to search 
                 selectInput("select",
                             label = h5("Choose from the following Wiki Pages on"),
                             choices = titles,
                             selected = titles, multiple = TRUE),
                 textInput(inputId = "txt",
                           label = h5("Add Search Terms")),
                 # Start Search
                 submitButton("Results")
    ),
    # Display Panel (Panel 3)
    mainPanel(                   
      h1("Display Panel",align = "center"),
      plotOutput("plot")
    )
  )
))
```

This is my server code:

```
library(shiny)
library(tm)
# library(stringi)
# library(proxy)
source("WikiSearch.R")

shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  output$plot <- renderPlot({ 
    
    # Progress Bar while executing function
    withProgress({
      setProgress(message = "Mining Wikipedia ...")
      result <- SearchWiki(input$select)
    })
    
    plot(result, labels = input$select, sub = "",main="Wikipedia Search")
  })
})
```

This is source code that is pulling from.

```
library(tm)
library(stringi)
library(WikipediR)
library(wordcloud)

SearchWiki <- function (titles) {
  articles <- lapply(titles,function(i) page_content("en","wikipedia", page_name = i,as_wikitext=TRUE)$parse$wikitext)
  
  docs <- VCorpus(VectorSource(articles)) # Get Web Pages' Corpus
  remove(articles)
  
  # Text analysis - Preprocessing 
  transform.words <- content_transformer(function(x, from, to) gsub(from, to, x))
  temp <- tm_map(docs, transform.words, "<.+?>", " ")
  temp <- tm_map(temp, transform.words, "\t", " ")
  temp <- tm_map(temp, content_transformer(tolower)) # Conversion to Lowercase
  temp <- tm_map(temp, PlainTextDocument)
  temp <- tm_map(temp, stripWhitespace)
  temp <- tm_map(temp, removeWords, stopwords("english"))
  temp <- tm_map(temp, removePunctuation)
  temp <- tm_map(temp, stemDocument, language = "english") # Perform Stemming
  remove(docs)
  
  # Create Dtm 
  dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(temp)
  dtm <- removeSparseTerms(dtm, 0.4)
  m <- as.matrix(dtm)
  v <- head(sort(rowSums(m), decreasing = TRUE),n = 50)
  dFcloud <- data.frame(word = names(v), freq = as.numeric(v))
  
  #Generate the wordcloud
  set.seed(2324)
  wordcloud(words = dFcloud$word,freq = dFcloud$freq, min.freq = 50)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Shot in the dark: Does this work?

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  output$plot <- renderPlot({ 
    
    # Progress Bar while executing function
    withProgress({
      setProgress(message = "Mining Wikipedia ...")
      SearchWiki(input$select)
    })
  })
})
```

It seems to me that the `SearchWiki` does not return anything and plots right away. However, I'm unsure if the `withProgress` will mess it up.

If not, try without the progress bar:

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  output$plot <- renderPlot({ 
    
    # Progress Bar while executing function
    SearchWiki(input$select)
  })
})
```

If this works but not above, you need could modify move the plotting line out of `SerachWiki` and into your original code.

Comment: Hi Anders, that partially worked. It did produce the wordcloud but I'm getting only character(0) on the wordcloud. That might be due to the sorting I have.

Comment: Seems like at problem with SearchWiki then. Can you give me an example of how to use SearchWiki and generate a wordcloud without  shiny?